# Why does concat RxJS operator emit Observables rather than values when concatenating multiple HttpClient calls in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am attempting to make several HTTP requests in response to a click on an "Update All" button.  My code looks like this:

```
let new_items:Observable<ApiResponse<ShoppingListItem>>[] = this.items
      .map(item => new ShoppingListItem(...))
      .map(item => this.shoppingListService.updateItem(item));


concat(new_items).subscribe(
  r => console.log(r);
);
```

`this.shoppingListService.updateItem` returns the Observable generated by calling `httpClient.put`.

When this code is run, I expect to see the value printed by `console.log(r)` to be of the type produced by the `updateItem` method.  Instead, it's an Observable.  My server logs indicate that no HTTP request was made.  This seems to indicate that it wasn't subscribed to.  My understanding of the `concat` docs is that each individual Observable passed to `concat` will be subscribed in sequence when the Observable before it completes.

If I replace `concat` with `forkJoin` I get the result I was expecting.  I don't particularly care about order, so I am fine using `forkJoin` but I want to understand why using `concat` didn't work.

Comment: Interesting.  It works as you expect if you spread the array `concat(...new_items)`. It might be a bug with `rxjs` or a bug with their documentation :-).  It sounds like it should allow an array as input, but I see what you've mentioned, that the subscription gets `Observable` not the emitted type. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-65431741?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @BizzyBob That does seem to be the issue.  Adding the spread operator changed the behavior to what I expected:  `concat(...new_items).subscribe()`
outputs the responses from the HTTP requests.  Write this up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is a little confusing but it's the expected behavior of `concat()` and `forkJoin()`.

`forkJoin()` works with both array of Observables and expanded Observables as individual arguments:

```
forkJoin(obs1, obs2, obs3)
// or
forkJoin([obs1, obs2, obs3])
```

But with `concat` it's different. It only expects source Observables (or [ObservableInput](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/type-alias/ObservableInput)) as individual arguments like the following:

```
concat(obs1, obs2, obs3)
```

But if you pass an array like `concat([obs1, obs2, obs3])` it takes the array as an ObservableInput and just iterates its items which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [RxJS's documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) we get the following description for the `concat` operator:

> Creates an output Observable which sequentially emits all values from
> given Observable and then moves on to the next.

the [forkJoin documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) expresses that it:

> Accepts an Array of ObservableInput or a dictionary Object of
> ObservableInput and returns an Observable that emits either an array
> of values in the exact same order as the passed array, or a dictionary
> of values in the same shape as the passed dictionary.

Using `forkJoin` the resulting observable would emit once an array with all the resulting values of the `updateItem` response observables, whilst `concat` would emit once for each of the `updateItem` response observables.

Comment: Yes, that's what the documentation says.  If you look at the documentation for `concat`, you will see it shows that the **values** emitted by the concatenated Observables are emitted by the Observable returned by the call to `concat`.  I am seeing `concat` emit the **Observables** themselves.

Comment: I just learned something... `concat` is not supposed to be used with an array argument (as per accepted answer), and `new_items` is an array in the question. I will ask the  RxJS people to add this to the docs.